# how to run angular server?

Tags: node.js, angular, server

Here is my code in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8080",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

I am trying to run `npm run start` it is compiled successfully but the port is not running. to build FE I am using npm run build it is working fine. so please guide me on how to run angular server

Comment: Is some other process already attached to this host port of 8080?

Comment: @xyz nope I have stopped it before I restart it

Comment: Did you mean ng serve? https://angular.io/cli/serve#ng-serve

Comment: what do you see in the angular console? is there any errors

Comment: @shadowman_93 yes

Comment: have you tried to use other port and check if it is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this command:

```
ng serve --open
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the terminal :

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

"start": "ng serve",
"start:prod": "ng serve --configuration=production",
"start:wp": "ng serve --configuration=production-wp",